# How do I use a flash.swf file with sql database?

Tags: sql, database, flash, integrate

I don't know a lot about flash, but I do know asp.net and javascript, and c#, etc.

I have designed some screens in flash that will be loaded up on a plasma tv.  What I need to be displayed in the screens I designed is data from my sql database.

Assigning the values to the boxes is no problem, but what is the format I should use to connect the flash screens to that database.  what would be the main lines of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, create a web service (asp.net would be good), and the flash make http request to the web service to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is executed on the client side, and thus won't have a direct connection to the database. You'll need to write some C# server-side code to handle the database connection.